# Index was outside the bounds of the array error?

Tags: c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[7] { new DataColumn("product_name"), new DataColumn("product_desc"), new DataColumn("product_price"), new DataColumn("product_qty"), new DataColumn("product_images"), new DataColumn("id"), new DataColumn("product_id") });
    if (Request.Cookies["aa"] != null)
    {
        s = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["aa"].Value);
        string[] strArr = s.Split('|');
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)

        {
            t = Convert.ToString(strArr[i].ToString());
            string[] strArr1 = t.Split(',');
            for (int j =0; j <= strArr1.Length; j++)
            {
                a[j] = strArr1[j].ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(a[0].ToString(),a[1].ToString(),a[2].ToString(),a[3].ToString(),a[4].ToString(),i.ToString(),a[5].ToString());
        }
    }
    d1.DataSource = dt;
    d1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: btw; it isn't clear what `a` is, as it isn't declared inside this method; that's *probably* a bad idea; you might want to move the declaration to be inside the method

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int j =0; j <= strArr1.Length; j++)
```

goes out of bounds on the last item; it should be

```
for (int j =0; j < strArr1.Length; j++)
```

---

As an aside: `strArr` is a `string[]`; `strArr[i]` is therefore a `string` (or `null`), so `strArr[i].ToString()` seems redundant, but `Convert.ToString(strArr[i].ToString())` seems *redundantly redundant*.

You can lose a *lot* of `ToString()` etc from this.